# programmatically added UILabel to the UITableView not loading properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to dynamically add `UILabel` to my `UITableViewCell`. So in `CellforrowAtIndex` event I did like this.

```
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
UILabel *lbl;
[[cell viewWithTag:100] removeFromSuperview];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];



}

lbl=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:cell.imageView.frame];
[lbl setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",[[[mutArrayPendingRequests objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"RequestItems"] count]]];
[lbl setTag:100];
[lbl setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[cell.contentView addSubview:lbl];
```

But my problem is when the table loads my text has not set to the `UILabel`. But Once I scrolled it loads for top 3 cells and bottom 3 cells. middle cells label not loading. What is the reason for this? How can I add a `UILabel`as a custom view to my UITableViewCell?
Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: remove this line `[[cell viewWithTag:100] removeFromSuperview];` and try

Comment: Then its overwritting the label values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The frame size which you are setting to the label i.e. `cell.imageView.frame` is invalid.

Set some proper frame value and check it will work.

```
lbl=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 20)];
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                      initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                      reuseIdentifier: simpleTableIdentifier];

        //create custom labels and button inside the cell view

        lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:cell.imageView.frame];
        lbl.tag = 100;
        lbl.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0];
        lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [lbl setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        [cell.contentView addSubview: lbl];
    }
   else {
        lbl = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
       }

   [lbl setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",[[[mutArrayPendingRequests objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"RequestItems"] count]]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    UILabel *lbl;
    [[cell viewWithTag:100] removeFromSuperview];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    }


    lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,200 ,40 )];
    [lbl setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",[[[mutArrayPendingRequests objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"RequestItems"] count]]];
    [lbl setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];         

    [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl];
  return cell;
}
```